# Getting Build Compilation Error when Integrating Firebase without Cocoapods [Obj-C]

Tags: firebase

I want to integrate Firebase without cocoapods in my iOS application which is in Obj-C. I had downloaded the firebase zip file containing all the xcframeworks and frameworks files. I am trying to implement Firebase Analytics with my application.

I had gone through the Readme.md file and followed the steps to integrate the Firebase with by project.

I had added all the required .xcframework and .framework files which are mentioned under the "Firebase Analytics" and made sure that I had tick marked the "Copy items if needed" and the "target" for my project is selected.

After this I added the "Firebase.h" header file in the same manner and also included the "-ObjC" tag under the "Build Settings -> Linking -> Other Linker Flags" but even doing all these steps when I am building my application I am getting the following error:

```
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked framework 'FBLPromises'
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SKProductsRequest", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in GoogleAppMeasurement(APMProductsRequest_9ec051498f83cad93a58cf3f308ab9b6.o)
  "_sqlite3_errmsg", referenced from:
      -[APMSqliteStore lastErrorMessage] in GoogleAppMeasurement(APMSqliteStore_4b93d70f10ae469a3a03d3a4cf33073f.o)
  "_sqlite3_bind_blob", referenced from:
      ___47-[APMSqliteStore bindValues:toStatement:error:]_block_invoke in GoogleAppMeasurement(APMSqliteStore_4b93d70f10ae469a3a03d3a4cf33073f.o)
  "_sqlite3_bind_double", referenced from:
      ___47-[APMSqliteStore bindValues:toStatement:error:]_block_invoke in GoogleAppMeasurement(APMSqliteStore_4b93d70f10ae469a3a03d3a4cf33073f.o)
  "_sqlite3_bind_text", referenced from:
      ___47-[APMSqliteStore bindValues:toStatement:error:]_block_invoke in GoogleAppMeasurement(APMSqliteStore_4b93d70f10ae469a3a03d3a4cf33073f.o)
  "_sqlite3_bind_int64", referenced from:
      ___47-[APMSqliteStore bindValues:toStatement:error:]_block_invoke in GoogleAppMeasurement(APMSqliteStore_4b93d70f10ae469a3a03d3a4cf33073f.o)
  "_sqlite3_column_int64", referenced from:
      -[APMSqliteStore valueAtColumn:forStatement:] in GoogleAppMeasurement(APMSqliteStore_4b93d70f10ae469a3a03d3a4cf33073f.o)
  "_sqlite3_column_double", referenced from:
      -[APMSqliteStore valueAtColumn:forStatement:] in GoogleAppMeasurement(APMSqliteStore_4b93d70f10ae469a3a03d3a4cf33073f.o)
  "_sqlite3_column_bytes", referenced from:
      -[APMSqliteStore valueAtColumn:forStatement:] in GoogleAppMeasurement(APMSqliteStore_4b93d70f10ae469a3a03d3a4cf33073f.o)
  "_sqlite3_prepare_v2", referenced from:
      -[APMSqliteStore prepareSQL:error:] in GoogleAppMeasurement(APMSqliteStore_4b93d70f10ae469a3a03d3a4cf33073f.o)
  "_sqlite3_changes", referenced from:
      -[APMSqliteStore deleteRecordsFromTableWithName:condition:parameterValues:error:] in GoogleAppMeasurement(APMSqliteStore_4b93d70f10ae469a3a03d3a4cf33073f.o)
```

Here is my System Configuration :

```
1.  Mac OS: MacOS Mojave[10.14.6]
2.  Xcode Version: 11.3.1
3.  Deployment Target: 11.3
```

Can anyone help me what I am missing here in the configuration that is needed to be done to successfully run it ?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on where you got your dependency from it should also include a `PromisesObjc.framework` file inside it. You need to simply drag this framework into your Frameworks, Libraries & Embedded Content part of Xcode and it will compile. If you don't have this, you'll need to download the FBLPromises framework and embed it yourself.

If you chose to use Carthage or CocoaPods it will gather this dependency for you but it may be in the list of your dependencies you mentioned.